# How to extend a class whose constructor has a parameter with type "Title" - @ angular / platform-browser type parameter

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to get/set web-page's title, and I'm doing it like this:

GetTitle.ts

```
import { Title }     from '@angular/platform-browser';
......
export class GetTitle {

    public constructor(private titleService: Title ) { }

    public setTitle( newTitle: string) {
      this.titleService.setTitle( newTitle );
    }
}
```

But! What if I want to make a new Sub-Class, which will inherit this one.
**How would I write a constructor in the child TestGetTitleClass?**
**How to make an instance of parent GetTitle class?**

TestGetTitleClass.ts

```
import {GetTitle} from "../path..";
let getTitleInstance : GetTitle = new GetTitle( ??? ?? );

export class TestGetTitleClass extends GetTitle{
   constructor(){
       super( ???? );
   }
}
```

Comment: just import it again and call super with it.

Comment: So, what's the matter? Do you know how to inherit classes in JavaScript? Are you new in OOP in TypeScript?

Comment: There's no need to override the constructor at all in the new class

Comment: this is basic OOP/Inheritance

Comment: If I understand it correctly, what you are trying to do is a mock of your class for testing purpose ? And you don't want to have a parameter in your test constructor ?

Comment: Yes, I want to test it, but I need an instance of that class, but for the instance, I need to use correct parameters with type Title. I'm trying to apply toskv answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll post here a bit of code with a working example I've done before, that way you might understand how it works :

**ComponentViewRightMode Class :** This class allows me to know the current user rights through the `ApplicationService` for a given URL (hence the `Router` dependency).

```
export class ComponentViewRightMode {
    private _routerReference: Router;
    private _applicationsServiceReference: ApplicationsService;
    viewRight: string;

    constructor(
        router: Router,
        applicationsService: ApplicationsService
    ) {
        this._routerReference = router;
        this._applicationsServiceReference = applicationsService;
        this.getCurrentUserViewRight();
    }

    getCurrentUserViewRight() {
        this.viewRight = this._applicationsServiceReference.currentViewReadMode(this._routerReference.url);
    }
}
```

**StockComponent Class :** Here is the syntax used. Notice how I need my component to have the dependencies injected with the use of `super()`.

```
export class StockComponent extends ComponentViewRightMode implements OnInit {

    constructor(
      private router: Router,
      private applicationsService: ApplicationsService,
      ...
    ) {
      super(router, applicationsService);
    } 
}
```

Basically, my need was for many components to have access to the `viewRight` property from my `ComponentViewRightMode` Class. Since the property is populated directly in the constructor of my top Class, all the components extending the class would have access to it asynchronously (because of my services).

Hence, I'm able to use my property my template as expected :

**StockComponent Template :**

```
<div class="stock-actions">
  >>>>> This is where I use the viewRight property <<<<<
  <button [disabled]="viewRight !== 'Write'" md-raised-button (click)="navigateTo('someURL')">
    {{'STOCK.EQUIPMENT_ADD'|translate}}
  </button>
  ...
</div>
```

Hope this working example helps you

Comment: you can do it mostly simple with protected vars

Answer (score 0):

I've recommend try this way

Your **Parent** class *(you could define a abstract class)*

```
export abstract class Titler {
  constructor(protected title: string) {}
}
```

*protected* property implies that the method or property is accessible only internally within the class or any class that extends it but not externally.

Your **Child** class

```
export class TestTitler extends Titler {
  constructor(protected title: string) {
     super(title);
  }
}
```

Your **SuperChild** class (is only example)

```
export class SuperChildTestTitler extends TestTitler {
  anyWayDoTitle(){
    return this.title;
  }
}
```